# How to pass id in href to show the details on nextpage using laravel

Tags: laravel

actually i am getting the all position details, but I need to show details of particular position while clicking a button in list of positions in a datatable.

demo1.blade.php

```
@foreach ($jobposts as $jobpost)
<tr>
<td>{{ $jobpost->job_code }}</td>
<td>{{ $jobpost->position }}</td>
<td>{{ $jobpost->department }}</td>
    <td>{{ $jobpost->location }}</td>
<td>{{ $jobpost->employement_type }}</td>
<td>{{ $jobpost->created_at }}</td>
<td><a href="/demo2"><button class="btn btn-default btn- 
    apply">Apply</button></a></td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

demo2.blade.php

```
@foreach ($jobposts as $jobpost)

<h4 class="heading color">Basic Eligibility Criteria: {{ $jobpost->position }}</h4>
<hr>

<p><strong>Job Code:</strong>  {{ $jobpost->job_code }}  </p>

<p><strong>Job Discription:</strong>  {{ $jobpost->job_discription }}   </p>

<p><strong>Skills Required:</strong>  {{ $jobpost->skills_required }}  </p>

<p><strong>Eligibility:</strong>  {{ $jobpost->eligibility }}  </p>

<p><strong>Package:</strong>  {{ $jobpost->package }}  </p>

<p><strong>Department:</strong>  {{ $jobpost->department }}  </p>

<p><strong>Location:</strong>  {{ $jobpost->location }}   </p>

<p><strong>Employement Type:</strong>  {{ $jobpost->employement_type }}  </p>

<p><strong>Note:</strong>  {{ $jobpost->detail }}  </p>

@endforeach
```

DemoController.php

```
public function index()
{
    $jobposts = DB::table('jobposts')->select('job_code','position','department','location','employement_type','created_at')->get();

    return view('home.demo1')->with('jobposts', $jobposts);
}

public function jobcode()
{
    $jobposts = DB::table('jobposts')->get();

    return view('home.demo2')->with('jobposts', $jobposts);
}
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/demo1', 'CareerController@index');
Route::get('/demo2', 'CareerController@jobcode');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<td><a href="/url/{{ $id }}"></a></td>
```

in web.php

```php
Route::get('/demo/{id}', 'DemoController@index');
```

in DemoController.php

```php
public function index($id)
{
   // Your code
}
```

Comment: please help me.

Comment: You need to show details of particular position while clicking a button in the list of positions in a data table. So pass the particular position `id` via URL and get id from the controller. in the controller, return the particular position details to the blade and show it.